# How can $ (x+b)^{2/3} - x^{2/3} $ be simplified using difference of cubes formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, cubics

How can $ (x+b)^{2/3} - x^{2/3} $ be simplified using difference of cubes formula?

I'm solving a question on differentiation and it led to this expression. How can this be simplified?

Comment: Related:L http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695421/how-is-xh1-3-x1-3-xh2-3-x1-3xh1-3-x2-3-si

Comment: Basically its cube root how can we make it cubic

Comment: I don't think it can. The formula in @labbhattacharjee's link is hardly a simplification!